# how to insert button ".com" on keyboard type email on iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, custom-keyboard

When focus `Entry` text with type keyboard is "Email" on device iOS,

Keyboard display:

[image: Keyboard type Email on iOS]

I want add to button `".com"` on this keyboard (or Replace button `"Space"` to button `".com"`)

This is keyboard type URL on iOS:

[image: keyboard type URL on iOS]

Please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS that is the "URL" keyboard (`UIKeyboardType.Url`):

#### iOS:

```
uiTextField.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Url;
```

#### Xamarin.Forms:

```
<Entry Keyboard="Url" />
```

Comment: May be you misunderstood my question. Because keyboard type "URL" don't have button "@". I want use keyboard type "Email" and have button ".com" or replace button "space" to ".com".

Comment: @HuuBaoNguyen You can not change the default iOS keyboards, you could add it to the "inputAccessoryView" which is on top the keyboards or you could create a custom keyboard from scratch (but you of course can  control that the user can change it at any time)

Comment: I can't add button ".com" on top the keyboards, because I use top of the keyboards that display button "Prev", "Next" (https://medium.com/@MrPonath/modifying-the-ios-keyboard-with-xamarin-bf3c988184d6). "Create a custom keyboard from scratch" ... What is this?